# Save images as string? IS it possible

Tags: python, string, image

Is it possible to save images as string, and then I load it up to Image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can save it to a StringIO buffer:

```
import pylab, numpy
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image

# plot a histogram
pylab.hist(numpy.random.rand(100))

buf = StringIO()
pylab.savefig(buf, format='png')

buf.seek(0)
im = Image.open(buf)
im.show()
```